# how to make a specific area of current view to be my view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

how can I obtain this bottom part of the view?
[image]

Since using `CGRectMake` can only get from top to bottom, it is possible or is there any other function to obtain that part of view using coordinates?

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -keyboardHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, tempViewHeight-toolbarHeight)];
```

since I'm using the negative value to set the y-coordinate, and this pull my view up, but the scroll bar can scroll out of bound and the content that extended above couldn't be seen.

Comment: means, u want screen shot of that view?

Comment: @AndeySatyanarayana no not screen shot, but actually the view, since I'm working on an messaging app, when the keyboard lifts the conversation tableview should lift as well but when i use -keyboardHeight for the y-coordinate, when i scroll on that view not all the rows can be scrolled since the upper part of the view is out of screen that makes me unable to scroll to that part when the keyboard is lifted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a CGRect for that highlighted area simply by providing the proper Y coordinate. Here is an example:

```
CGRectMake(0, yourView.frame.height/2, yourView.frame.width, yourView.frame.height)
```

This will give you the bottom half area of your view.

Comment: but how do i stick this bottom part to top of screen since the y-coordinate stays at bottom half, if u click on my link theres an image, i wanted to cut that part of view out and stick it back on top which is (x, y)= (0,0)

Comment: so are you trying to move that bottom half to the top of the screen?

For that you can do this:
    youView.frame.origin.y -= yourView.frame.height/2

Comment: i tried this, but this just push the whole view up too, the scroll bar still go out of the top bound

Comment: I am not able to clearly get what you are trying to achieve...there is no scroll bar visible in your screenshot...could provide more screenshots and explain more...

Comment: I wanna do sth like a messaging app that when keyboard lifts the whole conversation tableview shifts upwards, but if i do origin.y to be negative value, when i scroll to the uppermost row(keyboard still up), the row would be out of screen since origin.y is negative

Comment: yes that would be a limitation that user would have to deal with. Or perhaps you could just squeeze the tableview's height so that it would fit on the top part of the screen above the keyboard, when keyboard disappears it could stretch back to original size.

Comment: but for those popular chatting apps, they could perform such effect, so those functions arent built-in in xcode, did they create their own library to deal with such issue?

Comment: yes, they probably spent some time implementing a custom library or maybe subclassing some components like scrollview and tableviews.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
view.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:view];
view.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width,  self.view.frame.size.height);
```